# PHP switch with an array

Tags: php

I have a small PHP script that works perfectly such that when a person enters an EXACT match in to a form field, my PHP script will redirect to a website.

However, now I want to learn how to add the same functionality but not on an exact phrase, but on an array of words. Example, if a person enters a query containing any of the words "cake, batter, and red dye" the script will redirect to a web page (eg. How do I make cake batter using only red dye and butter) but if the query has green dye in it then the script will redirect to a different page.

Here is the code I have now for exact match case:

```
<?php
switch ($_REQUEST['zip']) {
case 'where is cape lookout':
case 'how far is cape lookout':
header("Location: http://www.example.com/cape-lookout");
break;
case 'where is cape hatteras':
case 'how far is cape hatteras':
    header("Location: http://www.example.com/cape-hatteras");
    break;
default:
    header("Location: http://www.example.com/search-404");
    break;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: You'd probably be better off (at a really simple level) just dropping something like Google Custom Search onto your site.

Comment: There is a lot of artificial intelligence involved in writing code for that sort of search, *How do I make cake batter using only red dye and butter* ;why re-invent the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep yor design with the `switch` statement, you could delegate the case definition 
to a function.

This function would accept the search query and return the case name.

You would also need to manually define the keywords for each case. This could be done by another function.

```
$query = "How do I make cake batter using only red dye and butter";

function defineCase($query)
{
    //Split the search query by a space character
    $queryArray = explode(' ', $query);
    //Iterate through the search cases
    foreach (getCases() as $case => $keywords) {
        //if all the search terms are present, return the case name
        if (count(array_diff($keywords, $queryArray)) === 0) {
            return $case;
        }
    }
}

function getCases()
{
    //Define here the keywords that must be present in the search query
    return [
        'cakes' => ['cake', 'batter', 'red', 'dye'],
        'pies' => ['flour', 'pastry', 'crust']
    ];
}

$case = defineCase($query);

switch ($case) {
    case 'cakes':
        //process
        break;
}
```

This solution is pretty simple and only gives you a hint how you could process.
It only handles words, not expressions.
You would need to take care of the proper search query sanitization and splitting.